# Query in different tables MySQL - Retrieve music playlists

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, the first one stores data on the songs, the second stores playlists with  the playlist name and the owner's id, the third one links the song ids to the playlists they belong to.

The question is how can I retrieve user's playlist and the songs they contains while limiting the number of requests to the server, is there a way to retrieve those informations in a single query ?

The PHP code that I have so far is at the end of my post.

Any help or advice will be great, I'm really getting crazy over that :)

Thanks

Table 1 `song_main`

```
   ID          song_artist          song_album            song_url           
   1             woops                 foo1                 www.                
   2              bob                  foo2                 www.
```

Table 2 `playlists`

```
  ID             title              owner_id               
   1           myplaylist               20                             
   1          myplaylist1               23
```

Table 3 `song_in_list`

```
   ID           song_id            playlist_id               
   1               1                   20                             
   1               1                   23
```

Here is the php code I have, I was basically thinking to get the playlist ids and name first, then run a second query to get the song ids that each playlist contain, then run a third query to get each song info. I just have no idea if what I'm doing is right...

```
 //Getting user's playlists 
    $raw_resultsplaylists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists
    WHERE (`owner_id` = '$userid')" ) or die(mysql_error());

    //fetch the query and adding them to vars               
    $counter = 1;
    while($resultsplaylists = mysql_fetch_array($raw_resultsplaylists))
              {         
    ${"playlistname" . $counter} = $resultsplaylists['id'];
    ${"playlistid" . $counter} = $resultsplaylists['playlistid'];
    $counter= $counter+1;
            }
```

Comment: Yes, you can use 1 query.  Use the JOIN function in your query

Comment: Thanks for you reply, how can I use the join function here ? because the three tables don't have a column in common.

Comment: You don't use 1 column for all three tables.  You JOIN one table to another using their common column THEN JOIN to the 3rd table using a common column in the 3rd table and one of the first two tables.  In your case JOIN song_in_list to the song_main via the song_id, then JOIN to playlists via playlist_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `song_main` (
  `ID`              varchar(255),
  `song_artist`     varchar(255),
  `song_album`      varchar(255),
  `song_url`        varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `song_in_list` (
  `ID`              varchar(255),
  `song_id`         varchar(255),
  `playlist_id`     varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `playlists` (
  `ID`              varchar(255),
  `title`           varchar(255),
  `owner_id`        varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Inserted this data:

```
INSERT INTO `song_main` (`ID`, `song_artist`, `song_album`, `song_url`) VALUES
(1, 'Artist 1', 'Album 1', 'www.url1.com'),
(2, 'Artist 2', 'Album 2', 'www.url2.com'),
(3, 'Artist 3', 'Album 3', 'www.url3.com'),
(4, 'Artist 4', 'Album 4', 'www.url4.com');

INSERT INTO `song_in_list` (`ID`, `song_id`, `playlist_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 2, 2),
(5, 4, 2),
(6, 4, 3);

INSERT INTO `playlists` (`ID`, `title`, `owner_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Playlist 1 for owner 1', 1),
(2, 'Playlist 2 for owner 1', 1),
(3, 'Playlist 1 for owner 2', 2);
```

Then I can use this query to get all songs in all playlists form user id 1:

```
SELECT songs.*, playlists.title as `playlist_title`
FROM song_main AS songs
JOIN song_in_list AS playlist_songs 
    ON songs.ID = playlist_songs.song_id
JOIN playlists 
    ON playlist_songs.playlist_id = playlists.ID
WHERE playlists.owner_id = 1
```

The result being:

```
ID  song_artist song_album  song_url    playlist_title
1   Artist 1    Album 1 www.url1.com    Playlist 1 for owner 1
2   Artist 2    Album 2 www.url2.com    Playlist 1 for owner 1
3   Artist 3    Album 3 www.url3.com    Playlist 1 for owner 1
2   Artist 2    Album 2 www.url2.com    Playlist 2 for owner 1
4   Artist 4    Album 4 www.url4.com    Playlist 2 for owner 1
```

You can easily add a playlist id too:

```
SELECT songs.*, playlists.title as `playlist_title`
FROM song_main AS songs
JOIN song_in_list AS playlist_songs 
    ON songs.ID = playlist_songs.song_id
JOIN playlists 
    ON playlist_songs.playlist_id = playlists.ID
WHERE playlists.owner_id = 1
AND playlists.ID = 1
```

Comment: You're welcome! I have to say though that @agrizzo also provided the correct answer. At almost the same exact time ;)

Answer (score 0):

The query would be (replace the * with the fields you need and fix the `WHERE` clause to be your PHP variable):

```
SELECT *
FROM playlists
JOIN song_in_list
  ON playlists.id = song_in_list.playlist_id
JOIN song_main
  ON song_main.id = song_in_list.song_id
WHERE playlists.owner_id = 'foo';
```